# Multer Cloudinary NodeJs

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to upload a image using `form-data` via postman to `cloudinary`
I am also using the npm package called `multer-storage-cloudinary`. However, I am having trouble. Here is my code:

```
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'ax850',
    api_key: config.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret:config.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET_KEY
});

let storage = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    folder: '/Memory',
    allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png'],
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(undefined, 'testing');
    }
});

let parser = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post('/upload', parser.array('images', 10), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

There is no error, it just freezes almost before crashing. I have a `/Memory` folder in my cloudinary.
Any ideas?

Comment: you need multer and cloudinary package and when defining the folder try without / so it will be `folder: "Memory",

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the following:

function processFile(e) {

```
    var f = document.getElementById('f');       
    var file = f.files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file', file);
    formdata.append('cloud_name', '<cloud_name>');
    formdata.append('resource_type', 'image');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload",true);


    xhr.onload = function () {
    // do something to response
        console.log(this.responseText);
    };

    xhr.send(formdata);     
}
```